# How to implement circular progress bar with progression text in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I'm trying to develop an application to understand android, application delete's default browser's history. Every thing is working fine, I'm using `AsyncTask` to accomplish the task with `ProgressDialog`

Here is how I'm deleting the `History`

```
ProgressDialog pd;

new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() 
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(HistoryClean.this, "Loading..",
                    "Please Wait", true, false);
        }//End of onPreExecute method

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            Browser.clearHistory(getContentResolver());

            return null;
        }//End of doInBackground method

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
        {
            pd.dismiss();               

        }//End of onPostExecute method
    }.execute((Void[]) null);//End of AsyncTask anonymous class
```

But instead of `ProgressDialog` I want to implement `CircularProgress` which it can display the progress value like `10% , 90%....`

Some times `History` may gets deleted faster and some times it may be slow, how to address this problem and dynamically update the `CircularProgress` bar with `Progression Values`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best two library i found on the net are on github
https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel
https://github.com/f2prateek/progressbutton?source=c
Hope that will help you

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask has method `onProgressUpdate(Progress... values)` that you can call each iteration for example or each time a progress is done during `doInBackground()` by calling  `publishProgress(Progress...)`.

Refer to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for more details

Comment: I referred the link you posted, thanks. But hoe to update it for `CircularProgressBar`